# What is the easiest way to expand HTML escape codes in UNIX?

Tags: html, unix, curl

My cUrl call is returning HTML code like:

```
&quot;Some stuff.&quot;
```

and I'd like to convert it to a UNIX string like:

```
"Some stuff."
```

Is there a way to do this without using search and replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perl -n -MHTML::Entities -e 'print decode_entities($_);'

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. When I replace `$_` with my variable, it isn't expanded because of the single quotes. The `-n` flag also causes this line to go into an endless loop. I have no perl background, btw.

Comment: You'd want to pipe your existing output through that perl command.  The -n causes the command to execute for each line in the input, and $_ is set to the value of each line.

e.g.: wget 'http://foo.com/bar' | perl -n -MHTML::Entities -e 'print decode_entities($_);'